# How to assign value to multiple keys in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is what I intend to do:

```
d = {}
d['a']['b'] = 123
```

What I expect is a dict like this:

```
{"a":{"b":123}}
```

But the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
```

Could anyone tell me how to do exactly what I want? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll first have to create the `a` nested dictionary:

```
d['a'] = {}
d['a']['b'] = 123
```

or create the nested dictionary fully formed:

```
d['a'] = {'b': 123}
```

or use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for the parent dictionary to have it create nested dictionaries for you on demand:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

d['a']['b'] = 123
```

If you expect this to work for any arbitrary depth, create a self-referential factory function:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

d = tree()

d['a']['b'] = 123
d['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'spam'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be more explicit.

```
d['a'] = { 'b': 123 }
```

You could probably use a defaultdict too, with an empty dictionary as the default value.